# Can you interpolate a variable into a {% include %} statement in a template?

Tags: django, django-templates

I know that you can use a variable directly in an include statement:

`{% include template-name %}`

But I have a variable that has only part of the name of the file to be included.   So I want to say somethning like

`{% include {{name}}.hmtl %}`

How can I achieve this effect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`add` template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#add):

```
{% with name|add:".html" as template %}
    {% include template %}
{% endwith %}
```